# How to make 'install USB' with custom Linux?

Tags: linux-kernel, system-installation, grub2, embedded, grub-legacy

I built my own custom kernel for new hardware.(Not a normal PC, embedded x86 device), and using [syslinux](http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php/HowTos) I could create a booting USB for that kernel.

After a few trial and errors, I was able to construct a working build image (and successfully booted the device with that kernel).

Now, I want to install that image not to usb but to the hard disk of embedded device. What can I do from now on? I searched for things about that, but the results are all about 'Install Linux branches with ISO.'

I really want to know how:

1. to install grub on 'empty' hard disk.
2. to install my custom kernel to the hard disk just like the '[ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)' does.